# Using gspread with proxy

Tags: python, sockets, gspread

I am trying to access google spreadsheets through `gspread api` in python. I have imported `gspread`. I am getting socket. `error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` at `gc = gspread.login('pan*******@gmail.com', '********')`

Here is my code:

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import gspread
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFont

w = 420

gc = gspread.login('pan******@gmail.com', '*******')
wks = gc.open("Spreadsheet").sheet1
```

I have checked that the username and password is correct. I have added two environment variables as `'http_proxy':'host:port'` and `'https_proxy':'host:port'`
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, since I am also working behind corporate proxy the `gspread` module didn't work for me and I got the same error as mentioned in the problem statement. I found one workaround i.e. use `script editor` in spreadsheet to write functions do things and you can call these function by send just http post request to the sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who might have this problem, I found out that gspread library doesn't support proxy connections. I ran it through normal connection and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure httplib to work throw proxy. For example for spreadsheet:

```
http = httplib2.Http(
    proxy_info=httplib2.ProxyInfo(httplib2.socks.PROXY_TYPE_HTTP_NO_TUNNEL,
                                  proxy_host, proxy_port,
                                  proxy_user=proxy_user, proxy_pass=proxy_pass))

httpAuth = credentials.authorize(http)  
service = apiclient.discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=httpAuth)  # using
```